# How to use filters in Angular JS by matching properties dynamically

Tags: angularjs, filter

I have a use case wherein I need to filter a list on the basis of selections from various drop down (one at a time). I am aiming at making a common function to be called on ng-change from dropdown as follows:

```
$scope.filterTasks = function(selection, filterOn) {
            if (filterOn === "trade") {
                $scope.tasks.forEach(function(t) {
                    if ((t.team.code === selection.team.code) && (t.deal.code === selection.deal.code)) {
                        t.filtered = "trade";
                    }
                    $scope.filterBy = "trade";
                });
            }
            else if (filterOn === "cluster") {
                //similar approach in this case
            }
        }
```

and in html I am doing something like:

```
<li ng-repeat="t in tasks | filter : {filtered: '{{filterBy}}'} : true track by t.tid" class="li_row" ng-if="!t.hide">
```

By default I am keeping filtered property as 'show' and $scope.filterBy = 'show', so that all the objects in array get displayed.

This do not seem to be working.

Is there some invalid approach up here. What can be a suitable way to achieve this. (i.e display all elements by default, and on selection from dropdown, display only those element where some deep properties of selection matches those properties in array objects).

I have found few post demonstrating above, but could not grasp much out of them

Comment: You could use `<select ng-model="filterOn">` and then in your filter func `if ($scope.filterOn === "trade") {....`

Comment: Didn't quite get your point here. What do I do in this function, How do I sepearate out the matched elements.

Comment: Additionally, I have various dropdown, so what's the way to tell my scope function that which dropdown has been used for selection. I mean how to pass this parameter back to controller

Comment: On the first select, add `ng-change="selectOneChanged(item)"`, on the second `ng-change="selectTwoChanged(item)"` and in your controller implement two methods `$scope.selectOneChanged(item)` and `$scope.selectTwoChanged(item)`. Those callbacks tell you which select was active.